# Why is assignment not allowed for extending indexed generics?

Tags: typescript, generics

```
export function blah<T extends { [key: string]: number[] }>(b: T, p: string) {
  b[p].push(3); // valid typescript
  b[p] = []; // ts(2536) Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'T'.
}
```

Is there some part of the documentation that covers this behavior so I can understand it better?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, okay, found it.  The particular error is due to an increased strictness when *writing* to index access types, implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) and [released in TypeScript 3.5](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#improved-excess-property-checks-in-union-types).

In general the compiler now complains if it can't be sure if you're writing the right value type to the property.  Specifically in this case:

> Given a type variable `T` with a constraint `C`, when an indexed access `T[K]` occurs on the target side of a type relationship, index signatures in `C` are now ignored. This is because a type argument for `T` isn't actually required to have an index signature, it is just required to have properties with matching types.

So when I call `blah()`, I can give an object that doesn't actually have an index signature:

```
blah({a: []}, "oops"); // no error
```

And therefore the compiler should possibly worry that `b[p]` does not exist.

---

The interesting thing here is that this added safety only happens when *writing* to the property and does not apparently matter when *reading* the property.  It still allows the pre-TS-3.5 behavior there, and since index signatures are unsound themselves (see [microsoft/TypeScript#13778](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778); they don't anticipate possible `undefined` values), your `push()` has a good chance of giving a runtime error.

---

So, uh, yay?  I'd say the answer here is a combination of #30769 and #13778.

Oh well, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this response. 
You said "your `push()` has a good chance of giving a runtime error."
under what type-compliant cases would a runtime error occur? I guess nulls might be in there, but I'm running `--strict`.

Comment: `blah({a: []}, "oops");` explodes at runtime because the `oops` property  is `undefined`.  Any time `p` is not a key of `b` you'll have a problem.  And `--strict` doesn't catch this because of microsoft/TypeScript#13778